# Idiomatic expressions with 'reciprocal or reciprocity' and retributive or retribution'

Tags: idiom-request

Does anyone know any idiom(s) using the words "reciprocal or reciprocality", please.

Comment: You need to be more specific. An idiom immediately comes to mind, but giving it would be no better than providing one in a long list. What criteria do you have for the answer that best suits your need? What have you already found and rejected, and why?

Comment: @  Bassford. The ones that suggest something like (for the reciprocal) "anything you do good or bad it will surely somehow come back to you", " whatever you do to me I will surely somehow return it", if you do for me I will do for you" etc and for the other is (the retributive) to suggest like "unforgiving situation which is quick to return bad for bad" etc.

Comment: Explaining why you want this would make this a better question. If you want an example sentence, have you tried a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I have a couple of dictionaries which I use, but you know before I refer to them, I must first have some idea of what I am looking for or learning about, like the recommended words given to me  on sites like this ie. an expression was suggested to me which I found/confirmed useful for my contextualization: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Paybacks%20a%20bitch%21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What goes around comes around**

or

**As you sow, so shall you reap**.

From ["Karma: What Goes Around Comes Around"](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/gadadhara-pandit-dasa/karma-what-goes-around-comes-around_b_1081057.html):

> “What goes around comes around” or “as you sow, so shall you reap” is the basic understanding of how *karma*, the law of cause and effect, works. The word *karma* literally means “activity.” *Karma* can be divided up into a few simple categories — good, bad, individual and collective. Depending on one’s actions, one will reap the fruits of those actions. The fruits may be sweet or sour, depending on the nature of the actions performed. Fruits can also be reaped in a collective manner if a group of people together perform a certain activity or activities.
>
> Everything we say and do determines what’s going to happen to us in the future. Whether we act honestly, dishonestly, help or hurt others, it all gets recorded and manifests as a karmic reaction either in this life or a future life. All karmic records are carried with the soul into the next life and body.

Comment: That makes sense, comment deleted, as this one will soon be